# gwt 2.7.0 background-image for body

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder, resourcebundle

I'd like my login page to have a background image in the body. Here's what I have so far:

```
public interface MyResources extends ClientBundle {
    public static final MyResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(MyResources.class);

    @Source("css/login.css")
    public MyLoginCssResource loginCss();

    @Source("css/GWT_App.css")
    public CommonCss commonCss();

    @Source("img/logo.png")
    @ImageOptions(repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.Both)
    ImageResource backgroundImage();
}

public interface CommonCss extends CssResource {

    String body();
}

.body {
    background-color: white;
    gwt-image: 'backgroundImage';
}
```

How do I reference the commonCSS in my ui.xml-file if I already have the loginCss referenced?

```
<ui:with field='res' type='client.resources.MyResources' />

<g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="{res.loginCss.maindiv}">
</g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UIBinder>
```

and also, how can I set a style for the body tag in a ui.xml-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I reference the commonCSS in my ui.xml-file if I already have the loginCss referenced?

```
<g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="{res.loginCss.maindiv} {res.commonCss.body}"/>
```

> and also, how can I set a style for the body tag in a ui.xml-file?

As far as i know you can't access body from ui.xml file.
There're a few ways to have this background ONLY in the login page.
The simplest one is to wrap all the page in a container block

```
    <g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="{res.commonCss.body}">
       <g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="{res.loginCss.maindiv} "/>
   </g:FlowPanel>
```

So on the navigation from the login page - the background won't stay there.

And in case you want a permanent effect - you can just add css in your index.html file, as a regular css for body tag

Comment: I just cannot  get the background-image to work. I got the body white by adding a style directly to the body element in the host html fil.e But the background image just wont show up, even though the correct style class is added to the  html element. Is there anything else I need to do to add a background-image to an HTMLPanel?

Comment: It should work out of the box. Also, you can just write background: url ('file.png') Please, check in the Dev Tools (F12 in chrome) 1. Is your style applied? 2 Is your Panel size meets expectations (may have 0 height) 3. Is the backgound file loaded (maybe path is wrong and you get 404)

Comment: It works now. I put everything into one css file and now it works. For some reason, the GWT_App.css wasn't loaded correctly. It did add the correct class name to the widget but the styles were never applied.